# Are there any hotkeys to intellisense a lambda in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda, visual-studio-2017

I find that typing lambdas can be cumbersome in visual studio. Is there any shortcut for a lambda expressions similar to how you can type ctor to generate a constructor? Even something as simple as `m => m.[StartIntellisenseHere]` or `() =>` would be good to have some quick snips for.  Are there any hotkeys like this I'm unaware of out of the box in Visual Studio, or with a free add in/extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. But you can define your own:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>lambda</Title>
            <Shortcut>lambda</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for lambda statement</Description>
            <Author>Me</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[(() =>
    {
        $selected$ $end$
    });]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

And save it on C:\Users[YOU]\Documents\Visual Studio 201?\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets

Comment: Thanks, this makes things easier & faster for me

Comment: For those who made the same mistake as I did, try saving this file with .snippet extension.